# When I give an input it always gives me valid. How can i fix it?

Tags: python

Basically my program is taking an input and trying to find that in a database (an array) and for
some reason even when its not in the array it displays valid.

I'm probably missing something but I just cannot find it.

```
CarNumbers = [
    {"number":"ABC 123", "oil":"10"},
    {"number":"ABC 124", "oil":"11"},
    {"number":"ABC 125", "oil":"12"}
]
IsValidCarNumber = False;

def check_database(msg):
    i = 0;
    for i in CarNumbers:
        print(msg);
        if i["number"] == msg:
            return True;
        else:
            return False;



def make_reply(msg, validNumber):
    reply = None
    if msg is not None:
        if validNumber:
            reply = "valid number!!"
        else:
            reply = "not valid number!"
        validNumber = False;
    return reply

update_id = None
while True:
    updates = bot.get_updates(offset=update_id)
    updates = updates["result"]
    if updates:
        for item in updates:
            update_id = item["update_id"]
            try:
                message = str(item["message"]["text"])
            except:
                message = None
            from_ = item["message"]["from"]["id"]
            check_database(message);
            reply = make_reply(message, check_database)
            bot.send_message(reply, from_)
```

Comment: You're passing the function `check_database` as `validNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

First your `check_database` should return `False` only when it has verifed all the values

```
def check_database(msg):
    for i in CarNumbers:
        if i["number"] == msg:
            return True
    return False
```

Then, in the loop you should use that valid, for now `make_reply(message, check_database)` pass the function **itself** which makes the condition always `True`. You need

```
from_ = item["message"]["from"]["id"]
valid = check_database(message)
reply = make_reply(message, valid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CarNumbers = [
    {"number":"ABC 123", "oil":"10"},
    {"number":"ABC 124", "oil":"11"},
    {"number":"ABC 125", "oil":"12"}
]
```

This first part is yust some compressing cause i dont like multiple return functions.

```
def check_database(msg):
    return i in (car["number"] for car in CarNumbers)

def make_reply(msg, validNumber):
        return None if not msg else "valid number!!" if validNumber else "not valid number!"
```

This is the part where your Error comes in. In Line 13 you passed the function (check_database) as a parameter instead of the function call (check_database(message)

```
1   update_id = None
2   while True:
3      updates = bot.get_updates(offset=update_id)
4      updates = updates["result"]
5      if updates:
6          for item in updates:
7              update_id = item["update_id"]
8             try:
9                 message = str(item["message"]["text"])
10            except:
11                message = None
12            from_ = item["message"]["from"]["id"]
13            reply = make_reply(message, check_database(message))
14            bot.send_message(reply, from_)
```

Comment: Just dumping a block of code isn't very helpful. Could you explain what the error was and what you changed?

Comment: Well the error is in the line "reply = make_reply(message, check_database(message))", where cou called it pasing the actual function as a parameter (pasing check_datatabse isntead of check_database(message)

Comment: And pasing a function will yust statically pass the function every call instead of calling it. So then you comparison if validNumber allways return True as a function is not None or False